# Loss of brightness/contrast when converting from Image<Gray,float> to Image<Gray,Byte>

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

We are using OpenCV with Emgu 2.4.9 wrapper.

When we convert the `Image<Gray,float>` to `Image<Gray,Byte>` (using `convert<Gray,Byte>()`), the brightness/contrast is reduced.
We are using `Image<Gray,Byte>` for display purposes while `Image<Gray,float>` is used temporarily for processing (e.g. convolution).

However, when `Image<Gray,float>` is saved as JPEG, I see the required level of intensities/brightness.

When I checked the `Image.Save()` method, it looks like it finally ends up calling OpenCV imwrite_() function which in turn converts the Float image to byte format: ‘image.convertTo( temp, CV_8U );’

So, I would expect the intensity level to have reduced when `Image<Gray,float>` is saved to JPEG. But it does not (even though, the same convertTo() method, which in turn calls OpenCV cvt_() function).

But, when the float image converted to Byte and saved the brightness/contrast is reduced.

In both cases, I believe, `saturate_cast<>` would be called.

Related questions here: [Emgu image conversion from Image<Gray,float> to Image<Gray,Byte> results in intensity loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793886/emgu-image-conversion-from-imagegray-float-to-imagegray-byte-results-in-inte)

Would someone be able to describe what is going on and how to preserve the brightness/intensity when converting from `Image<Gray,float>` to `Image<Gray,Byte>`?